# How do you determine from a BPL if it is design time only

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe

We build all our packages to the same output directory.

The directory includes both design time and runtime packages.

Looking at the resulting BPL's is there a way to determine that a packages is Design Time only?

I want to be able to filter these out of my deployment list, as I am building with runtime packages.

In the past I have built custom lists, of the run time packages.   I am looking for away to automate this process.

We are using Delphi XE if there is a version specific answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`GetPackageInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/SysUtils.GetPackageInfo) and check for `pfDesignOnly` in the `Flags` parameter.
Or, if you'd like to skip the unnecessary enumeration of contained units and required packages, have a look at `PackageInfoTable` in `SysUtils` (which is, unfortunately, hidden in the implementation section).

Comment: If you are only loading the resources represented by PackageInfoTable, you can use LoadLibraryEx() with the DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES flag instead of LoadPackage().  This avoids running the package initialization and package dependency checks.  This solved many of my problems (messageboxes, exceptions, etc.).  You can copy the code for PPackageInfoHeader, TPackageInfoHeader and PacakgeInfoTable() out of SysUtils into your own units to use them.  Don't confuse the SysUtils.PackageInfoTable() method with the System.PackageInfoTable record.

Comment: @phil-gilmore Yes but since `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as for backwards-compatibility only, perhaps it's better to do the same as `SysUtils.GetPackageDescription`, ie. `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, not externally without analyzing the `imports` of the BPL to see if it has any dependencies on the design-only IDE packages (eg., `DesignIntf`). You can do this with `TDump` or [DependencyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com). You can also use TOndrej's suggestion if you want to try and load the packages with an app.

A quick check of one of the design only packages on my system with DependencyWalker shows this:

[image: DependencyWalker image]

The usual solution to this issue (as you can see in the Virtual Treeview package in the image) is to add a `D` suffix to design-time packages; some component sets (like some of the TurboPower ones, IIRC) use an `R` suffix for runtime packages as well.

Comment: It's only a resource, no analyzing of imports is required. You can load the package with `LoadLibraryEx` specifying `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`, like `SysUtils.GetPackageDescription` does.

Comment: @TOndrej: What's only a resource? I'm referring to checking the library (BPL) itself for dependencies on loading DesignIDE or DesignIntf. I've updated my answer with an image to explain. - Saw your second comment after adding my edit. Thanks. :)

Comment: I meant the 'PACKAGEINFO' resource which contains the information about the package. A package may not require any of Delphi's design packages but still be design-only itself.

Comment: Can't edit comments anymore. To clarify and sum it up: A package is design-only if it's flagged so by the compiler (project options) - these flags are stored in the 'PACKAGEINFO' resource. Whether it imports Delphi's design packages is irrelevant.

Comment: @TOndrej: Ah... Thanks for clarifying. Can you give an example of such a package (other than those used in the IDE itself and distributed in the installation)? I can't think of any reason that one would be design-time only but not require design-time packages. - Again, our comments crossed. Got it - BPL can be flagged design only for no other reason than that the developer felt like it when the package was built.

Comment: I've made several design-time packages that didn't require any of the IDE's packages. The design-time packages did nothing but call `RegisterComponents`, but that's in plain old *Classes.pas*. I didn't strictly need a design-time package at all, but I made it anyway in case I needed to add more design-time-specific functionality later.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks. I'd thought of that (along with the final sentence of my last comment to TOndrej); that's why I didn't suggest checking for a dependency on RegisterComponents (or Register itself). It's a good point.